# Symfony2, KnpPagination Bundle:Sorting using icons

Tags: symfony, twig, knppaginator

I am using KNPPanginator Bundle, and pretty satisfied with it.

But i cannot find out, how to replace my sorters at the top, with icons instead of text. Here is my Twig code:

```
    {% block pagination_head %}
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>{{ pagination.sortable('likes', 'u.likePoints')|raw }}</th>
        <th>{{ pagination.sortable('title', 'u.title')|raw }}</th>
        <th>{{ pagination.sortable('date', 'u.created')|raw }}</th>



    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endblock %}
```

So what do i need to do, to get a thumps up icon, instead of the word "like"?
i tried pasing an `<img src...>` in there, but did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to have an image asset of a thumb-up. Let's say you do get one and put it here: `web/images/like.png`

Then all you need to do is this (assuming `pagination.sortable('likes', 'u.likePoints')` returns the string "like"):

```
<th>{{ asset( "images/" ~ pagination.sortable('likes', 'u.likePoints') ~ ".png" }}</th>
```

Of course, you'll probably want to put the image resource in your bundle and publish it with `assets:install web`, for encapsulations/organizational purposes.

### EDIT

There are a lot of ways to solve what you're talking about.  One would be to make a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

In Your\Bundle\Resources\views\Macros\bootstrap.html.twig

```
{% macro icon_class( type ) %}
  {% set type_class_map = {
    like: 'icon-user'
  } %}
  {{ type_class_map[type] }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then, in the template you need it in

```
{% import "YourBundle:Macros:bootstrap.html.twig" as bootstrap %}

{% set heading = pagination.sortable('likes', 'u.likePoints') %}
<th class="{{ bootstrap.icon_class(heading) }}">{{ heading }}</th>
```

Comment: well i am using twitter bootstrap for icons, so i would be rather using something like <i class="icon-user"></i> to represent an icon.

Comment: thanks for your ideas. i did the code here http://pastebin.com/taJZtZQq, but then i get the error: Key " 
<a class=sortable href=/app_dev.php/browse?sort=likePoints&amp;direction=asc&amp;page=1 title=likePoints>likePoints</a>
" for array with keys "likePoints" does not exist in /coding/mynewsite/src/Tracker/MembersBundle/Resources/views/Macros/bootstrap.html.twig at line 5 ......so it seems to expect an array in different form.